# Cron job : dump and scp tar dump to remote server

Tags: ssh, cron, tar, scp

I want to make a cron job that dumps a MySQL database and `tar`s the dump with date|hour|minute and then `scp`s it to a remote server.

```
0 */2 * * * mysqldump -uroot myBase>myBase.sql && tar -zcf /var/backups/myBase`-date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.tar.gz myBase.sql && ...
```

Now I'm missing the `scp` part.

I don't know how to get the `.tar.gz` file newly created with its date/hour/minute suffix.

Comment: I would write a script , set a variable for the date, and then you can use the date variable in scp. You then call the script from cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need `scp`, just compress the file and write it to remote path would be enough.

```
tar cvzf - /path/to/myBase.sql | ssh USER@HOST "dd of=/path/to/backups/myBase$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).tar.gz"
```

The `-` telling `tar` command to don't create output file, instead it will write outputs into stdout. see [man tar](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/tar.1.html).

You can use `cat >/path/to/bsckups/...` as well instead of `dd`.

Even you can use `rsync` with `-z` option which compares the file before transfer but it will decompress after transfer in remote path.

Or you could dump directly to remote path if compression is not the matter.

```
mysqldump .... | ssh USER@HOST "dd ..."
```

Also you can use `-h` option of `mysqldump` like below in remote server (which is local now) and dump from local server (which is remote server now):

```
mysqldump -h HOSTNAME/IP ...  > /path/in/local
```

Comment: thank you, what is the extension "- -T" for?

Comment: I updated my answer